# iOS FPS low frame rate when character moves, profiler shows Physics.Simulate takes cpu time

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, unity-game-engine, physics

We develop FPS game for iOS. Player character is a First Person Controls from Standard Assets (Mobile). It has standard Character Controller attached.

We have 7 enemies on our scene Each enemy has a non-kinematic RigidBody. Enemies moving to the player when player is near

Scene has 5500 triangles / 6000 verts We have 20-25 fps on iPhone 4 when player don't move. When player start moving, fps falls to 7-10.

Also, we move enemies by changing their transform directly, not by calling AddForce.

In profiler we can see that Physics.Simulate takes about 60%-70% of cpu when the player moves.

How should we fix this?

We are new to Unity and 3D. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Unity's documentation using the Physics engine in iOS devices has a performance penalty since it relies heavily on floating point number operations. http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/iphone-basic.html

In order to increase performance, as the documentation suggests, avoid Mesh Colliders, set a Low Fixed Frame Rate, and enable Rigibody Interpolation.

> **Can I make a game that uses heavy physics?** 
>   A: Physics can be expensive
>   on iOS is it requires a lot of floating point number crunching. You
>   should completely avoid MeshColliders if at all possible, but they can
>   be used if they are really necessary. To improve performance, use a
>   low fixed framerate using Edit->Time->Fixed Delta Time. A framerate of
>   10-30 is recommended. Enable rigidbody interpolation to achieve smooth
>   motion while using low physics frame rates. In order to achieve
>   completely fluid framerate without oscillations, it is best to pick
>   fixed deltaTime value based on the average framerate your game is
>   getting on iOS. Either 1:1 or half the frame rate is recommended. For
>   example, if you get 30 fps, you should use 15 or 30 fps for fixed
>   frame rate (0.033 or 0.066)

Comment: In my Unity I dont have  Edit->Time->Fixed Delta Time. I changed Edit->Project Settings->Time-> Fixed Timestep. Is this right?